# Make a new repository out of existing repository along with all its code?

Tags: git, github

I have started working with git recently. I am trying very simple thing which I am not sure how to do that.

I have a repository like this -

```
Testing/ABC
```

And inside above repository, I have certain projects. Now I am trying to clone this repository and make a new repository like this -

```
Testing/PQR
```

Meaning, whatever is inside `ABC` repository, it should come inside `PQR` repository automatically and then I can push this repository to github.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We are going to have two code base, one for some other projects and other for different projects so that is the reason, I need to do this.

Comment: Have you already created a new empty repo on (PQR) on github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already created a new, empty repository on github named `PQR`, you can follow these steps:

```bsh
# clone original repo
git clone git@github.com:yourcompany/ABC.git PQR

# Set origin to the new repo
cd PQR
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourcompany/PQR.git

# Now push all the branches and tags to the new repo
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Comment: A potentially quicker solution would be to clone the local repository to save downloading from GitHub.